# How to test numpy arrays that are not only numeric for almost equality?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, testing, double

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1/3, 2, None])
a
Out[11]: array([0.3333333333333333, 2, None], dtype=object)
b = np.array(a)
b
Out[13]: array([0.3333333333333333, 2, None], dtype=object)
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(a, b)
```

outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "<ipython-input-14-f86262d61654>", line 1, in <module>
    np.testing.assert_almost_equal(a, b)   File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 585, in assert_almost_equal
    return assert_array_almost_equal(actual, desired, decimal, err_msg)   File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 1047, in assert_array_almost_equal
    precision=decimal)   File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 794, in assert_array_compare
    val = comparison(x, y)   File "C:\code\EPMD\Kodex\EPD_Prerequisite\python_3.7.6\lib\site-packages\numpy\testing\_private\utils.py", line 1038, in compare
    z = abs(x - y) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

How do I avoid for loops here?

Comment: `no loops` in `numpy` really means using fast compiled loops, which mostly just work with numeric dtypes. Math on object dtype arrays is slower, at list comprehension speed.

Comment: Is there a workaround? these are very large arrays that should work in real time. I was hoping not to change the source

Comment: @hpaulj Also, doesn't "no loops" also utilize parallelism?

Comment: `numpy` code that works with numeric dtypes can release the `gil` and gain some multicore speed (low level parallelism).  But an object dtype array contains references to Python objects like `None` and python floats.  So it can't use `no-gil`.  In any case, the big difference is between Python level iterations and compiled code operating on a compact numeric data buffer.

Comment: In general, object dtype arrays have few, if any speed advantages, over lists.